# How to functionally evaluate a series with a constant inside of a trig function i.e. rewrite the sum as a function of the constant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

For example, is there another way to write
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{\sinh(an\pi)}$$
so that it can be written as a function of the constant and the series can then be evaluated for any value of the constant?

I'm basically asking if we can create $f(a)$ from $S$ like we would for say a power series.

I would assume that we would normally want to find a way to get the constant outside of the sum, but the constant being inside of $\sinh$ complicates things. That would be if we were trying to evaluate the series and have a constant leftover to plug in for like say $\sum_n \frac{1}{k} a_n = f(k)$. I tried to rewrite the example I provided above by using a pole expansion representation of $csch(z)$ to rewrite the series, but I couldn't figure out how to get it into a form that can be easily rewritten as a function. Any insight or advice on what might work would be greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT: I played around a bit in WolframAlpha, and it looks like in some cases like [THIS ONE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=f%5C%2840%29a%5C%2841%29+%3DSum%5BDivide%5Bsinh%5C%2840%29an%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) where we want to find a function $f(a) = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{sinh(an)}{n}$, there are ways to find a functional representation of the series, I just don't know nearly enough about the process to know how this was done or how it can be applied to this example. It times out every time I attempt this for $\csc(an)$ or $\sec(an)$ so I'm assuming division by 0 is being done somewhere in whatever the process is.

Comment: I don't think the constant is the real problem here.  If it was just $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(n^2 \sinh(n))$ would you be able to evaluate it?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes that series should be able to be evaluated. I didn't do the evaluation of that myself, but [I plugged it into wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bn%2C2%5Dsinh%5C%2840%29n%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) and it looks like it works to me.

Comment: If you want to numerically evaluate the series $$S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{1}{\sinh(a n \pi)}$$ then you need to define the constant $a$. I don't see any other way around it since WolframAlpha gives a numerical result for the simpler series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{1}{\sinh(n)}$$ versus a closed form.

Comment: @StevenClark I just realized that my question was not worded quite right. I'm actually looking for a way to represent the sum in a functional manner, not evaluate it in a numerical one. It would be the same as if we were to rewrite a geometric series as a function and vice versa. For example $$\sum_{n \ge 0}(-1)^n\frac{a^{2n+1}}{(2n-1)} = \arctan(a) \ \ : -1 \le x \le 1$$. I was trying to rewrite the sum in some way to maybe get it in a form that has a known functional form. Yeah I totally screwed up in the title too. Oops. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: The trivial answer is that you *already have* written this as a function of the constant: this is simply the function $f(a) = \sum_n 1/n^2\sinh(na\pi)$. Are you asking whether this can be simplified, perhaps using trig functions, to get rid of the summation?

Comment: @Sambo I want to know if there is anything that can be done to represent the series in a different way so that it is no longer a series. Something that can be evaluated by only having to plug in for the constant, a. The $\arctan(a)$ example would be an example of a series being represented as a function that is no longer a series and can be evaluated by simply plugging in a.

Comment: @ResearcherR But what's $\arctan$ if it's not s series?

Comment: @ancientmathematician A function? I'm looking to go from a series representation *back* to a functional representation. When a variable is inserted, we want to look for a functional definition.

Comment: In most developments of mathematics the trig functions are defined as infinite series, and just because some functions have names they are no better than functions which don't have names. As @Sambo has said you have written your $S(a)$ as a function as soon as you know the infinite series converges.

Comment: @ancientmathematician okay now I understand. Perhaps I should transform the question then as I didn't fully understand the terms that I had laid forth in my question. Then it is exactly as sambo suggested which was to find a way to represent this function as a non-series. I should probably take this question down and post a revised one now that my terms are straigtened out and it hopefully won't confuse anyone who reads it this time. Thank you for shining a light on what I was failing to understand!